# Semantics of various *nix command and option names

Tags: linux, shell, command

There are various obscure commands and options in *nix. Some are easier to associate to like: q for quit and so on. I am pretty sure that all the command names and options name have some meaning behind. Please keep sharing what you know or point to some resources on net. I searched for a while but didn't get a good resource.

[This question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/6ed267/semantics_behind_naming_and_options_for_various/)

Comment: If you mean all of the various (and obscure) commands on Unix systems, this becomes _really_ broad. For some specific cases there might be sensible answers, though most often it's probably just about initials, and perhaps second, or middle letters if the initials clash

Comment: Yes, It's really broad.. but instead of rote learning or taking one at a time.. I am looking for some definitive guide or something of that sort.. Individual contribution and knowledge would be welcome

Comment: Start with `man man` and `man less` and `help help` and go from there.  This is impossibly broad.  **Just read the site you're on**; there are thousands of "individual contributions" and a lot of knowledge already here.  If you won't take the time to read what's there or even look through it, or frame an actual specific question, why should others take the time to compile a hodgepodge of information into one single page?

Comment: Since you used the "shell" tag, I'll point you to the questions/answers linked directly from the "about me" section of my profile page (which are mostly *not* written by me, they're just some of the best pieces of crucial shell scripting know-how on this site).

Comment: There is no specific answer for this question. Every other tool produced by different developer. There is no naming convention standard in the world for applications. You should take a look man pages.

Comment: This is also primarily opinion-based. :) Take f.i. `vi`: the first ~20 keys might have had some meaning behind them, then the meaning for the remaining ones was: "there's no better shortcut left".

Comment: **There is no standard for the meaning of options** There are some groups of programs with a common syntax. But the syntax may even then not be strictly consistent. **What you look for does not exist!** (But it should, as complete as feasible, if you ask me. It's very hard to do, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Questions asking for learning materials are off topic here, unless it's related to the official POSIX documentation of standard utilities.

This may be found in [the "Shell and Utilities" section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/idx/xcu.html) of [the POSIX 1003.1-2008 standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/).

There you may find a list of all shell utilities and each utility described in detail, including what their options do, and often even examples of use.

You should also read the manual on your system for the tools that you use to familiarise yourself with them. The utilities on your system will likely be mostly POSIX compliant, but may well extend their repertoire of usage beyond what's required by the standard. Other tools are simply not standardized because their use falls outside of what the standard applies to.

When it comes to the letters used for options; Some utilities have lots of options, and it would be difficult to find meaningful names for them, especially if only the short one-letter options are used. However, options that are used across multiple utilities *often* (but not always) has the same name and semantics, such as `-t` or `-d` for "delimiter", or `-o` to specify the name of an output file.  The Rationale section of some standard POSIX utilities may give the reasoning for the particular choice of options in some cases (like [the discussion about the `-b`/`-c` option for `tail`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/tail.html)).